# match this pattern and make it as a list for all process

Tags: python, regex, perl

hi i have filtered the file in following format.

```
  ====================================================================
  ===== Usage
   ====================================================================
  --------------------------------------------------------------------
   ----- Processes: 
   --------------------------------------------------------------------

          PID PPID USER       VSZ STAT COMMAND
1     0 admin      812 S    init       
2     0 admin        0 SW   [kthreadd]
3     2 admin        0 SW   [migration/0]
4     2 admin        0 SW   [ksoftirqd/0]
5     2 admin        0 SW   [watchdog/0]
146     1 admin      712 S    /usr/sbin/in.tftpd -l -u nobody -s /etc/airespi
3442     1 admin     4640 S N  /usr/sbin/snmpd udp:161,udp6:161 -a -p /var/run
```

currently i tried

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import re

logfile = open('diag.txt','r')

for line in logfile.xreadlines():
if line.find('Processes') >=0 :
    line = logfile.next()
    line = logfile.next()
if line.find('PID PPID USER       VSZ STAT COMMAND') >= 0 :
       Headers = re.findall(r"[\w']+", line)
       print Headers
       line = logfile.next()
else:
       exit
while(line.find('APmgr info: apmgrinfo -a') == -1):
    #temp = re.findall('[/w]',line)
    print temp
    line = logfile.next()
```

Here i tried to read the file untill it matches Process. Then i ignore one line. After that i put PID PPID USER VSZ STAT COMMAND in a list

Now again i read next line in loop. Here i want to put them all in a list. i tried [/w] but its not splinting properly .

I have a code in perl already which is doing the match as follows

```
     until($nextline =~ m/\-\-\-\-\- APmgr info: apmgrinfo -a/){
            my @temp = ();
            if($nextline =~ m/\s*?(PID)\s*(PPID)\s*(USER)\s*(VSZ)\s*(STAT)\s*(COMMAND)/){
                push @Headers, $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6;
            }elsif($nextline =~ m/\s*(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([a-zA-Z_]+)\s+(\d+)\s+([a-zA-Z_]+)\s+(.*)$/){
                my %processes = ();
                @temp = split(/\s+/,$nextline);
                $processes{$Headers[0]} = $1;
                $processes{$Headers[1]} = $2;
                $processes{$Headers[2]} = $3;
                $processes{$Headers[3]} = $4;
                $processes{$Headers[4]} = $5;
                $processes{$Headers[5]} = $6;
                push @Process,\%processes;
            }
            $nextline = <INFILE>;
        }
        last;
    }
}###End of while loop###
```

Comment: What does *"its not splinting properly"* mean? What were you expecting the output to be, and what do you actually get?

Comment: please use proper intendation for your code

Comment: What are you trying to do? You've shown us the input and the attempted solution, but not the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: A list should create form me. Which should contain the values like this, [2,0,admin,0,SW,[kthreadd]] . So each time inside a loop i will get a list . which i will append in a main list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.split` should do it for you:

```
temp = re.split('[^\w\[\]\/\-:]+', line)
```

In your case you should better compile re and then use the compiled version:

```
re_line = re.compile('[^\w\[\]\/\-:]+') 
while(line.find('APmgr info: apmgrinfo -a') == -1):
    temp = re_line.split(line, 6)
    print temp
    line = logfile.next()
```

Of course you should refine a regex itself to match better for your problem. Mine is based only on your example.

Comment: This solution works for me. But it give me a list like below,['', '5913', '1', 'admin', '4380', 'S', '/bin/smsd', ''] . But i need list only with values like ['5913', '1', 'admin', '4380', 'S','/bin/smsd']

Comment: `re.split` returns a list, so I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Final value of the list is like this ['', '146', '1', 'admin', '712', 'S', '/usr/sbin/in', 'tftpd', '-l', '-u', 'nobody', '-s', '/etc/airespi', ''].  But it should be like ['', '146', '1', 'admin', '712', 'S', '/usr/sbin/in tftpd -l -u nobody -s /etc/airespi']. Final command part should be in a single string in the list

Comment: Looks like you used not the latest version of my answer. Be sure to use `re_line.split(line, 6)`

Comment: Hi this one works for me. To be more familiar with regular expression apart from python documentation, is there any good tutorial where i can learn more advanced concepts and examples in python

Answer (score 1):

Your perl code could be simplified greatly.

There's no need to use a regex to capture your data, as it's just white space separated.  Therefore `split` can accomplish everything you want much more cleanly.  The only trick is to recognizing that you want only 6 values, and therefore need to limit the number of times that you split your data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @header;
my @processes;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next if ! /^\s*\w/;

    if (! @header) {
        @header = split ' ';
    } else {
        my @data = split ' ', $_, 6;
        my %hash;
        @hash{@header} = @data;
        push @processes, \%hash;
    }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@processes;

__DATA__
  ====================================================================
  ===== Usage
   ====================================================================
  --------------------------------------------------------------------
   ----- Processes: 
   --------------------------------------------------------------------

          PID PPID USER       VSZ STAT COMMAND
1     0 admin      812 S    init       
2     0 admin        0 SW   [kthreadd]
3     2 admin        0 SW   [migration/0]
4     2 admin        0 SW   [ksoftirqd/0]
5     2 admin        0 SW   [watchdog/0]
146     1 admin      712 S    /usr/sbin/in.tftpd -l -u nobody -s /etc/airespi
3442     1 admin     4640 S N  /usr/sbin/snmpd udp:161,udp6:161 -a -p /var/run
```

Outputs:

```
[
  {
    COMMAND => "init       ",
    PID     => 1,
    PPID    => 0,
    STAT    => "S",
    USER    => "admin",
    VSZ     => 812,
  },
  {
    COMMAND => "[kthreadd]",
    PID     => 2,
    PPID    => 0,
    STAT    => "SW",
    USER    => "admin",
    VSZ     => 0,
  },
  {
    COMMAND => "[migration/0]",
    PID     => 3,
    PPID    => 2,
    STAT    => "SW",
    USER    => "admin",
    VSZ     => 0,
  },
  {
    COMMAND => "[ksoftirqd/0]",
    PID     => 4,
    PPID    => 2,
    STAT    => "SW",
    USER    => "admin",
    VSZ     => 0,
  },
  {
    COMMAND => "[watchdog/0]",
    PID     => 5,
    PPID    => 2,
    STAT    => "SW",
    USER    => "admin",
    VSZ     => 0,
  },
  {
    COMMAND => "/usr/sbin/in.tftpd -l -u nobody -s /etc/airespi",
    PID     => 146,
    PPID    => 1,
    STAT    => "S",
    USER    => "admin",
    VSZ     => 712,
  },
  {
    COMMAND => "N  /usr/sbin/snmpd udp:161,udp6:161 -a -p /var/run",
    PID     => 3442,
    PPID    => 1,
    STAT    => "S",
    USER    => "admin",
    VSZ     => 4640,
  },
]
```